# Model with ManyToMany relationship not persisted with Doctrine in symfony when updated

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I try to update a model, but this last one is not persisted when calling flush() from entityManager.

The code is as follow

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=GroupBase::class, inversedBy="baseUsers", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $GroupBase;
```

```
// this is the variable used in the entity GroupBase

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=BaseUser::class, mappedBy="GroupBase", cascade={"persist"})
 */
    private $baseUsers;
```

```
// this is the Entity GroupBase, which should contain a collection of User 

public function addBaseUser(BaseUser $baseUser): self
    {
        if (!$this->baseUsers->contains($baseUser)) {
            $this->baseUsers[] = $baseUser;
            $baseUser->addGroupBase($this);
     
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

```
// this methods is the one that insert Users in the GroupBase Collection 

 public function insertUsersGroup(LdapUser $ldapUser, GroupBase $groupBase){
        /**
         * this methods aim to insert all Users that belong to group Members into GroupBase  
         */
        
        $dn = $ldapUser->getDistinguishedName();
        $members = $groupBase->getMembers();
        
        if(in_array($dn, $members)){
            $groupBase->addBaseUser($ldapUser);
            $ldapUser->addGroupBase($groupBase);
        }
        return $groupBase;
   }
```

this is the controller that insert Users in groups

```
/**
     * @Route("group/insertUsersGroup")
     */
    public function insertUsersInGroup(){
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $ldapUsers = $entityManager->getRepository(LdapUser::class)->findAll();
        $groupBase = $entityManager->getRepository(GroupBase::class)->findAll();
        foreach($groupBase as $group){
            foreach($ldapUsers as $user){
                $this->service->insertUsersGroup($user, $group);
                try{
                    $entityManager->persist($group);
                    $entityManager->flush();
                    $response = "model saved";
                }
                catch(Exception $e){
                    throw $e;
                }
            }
        }
        return new Response(
            $response
        );

    }
```

If I call  the methods $groupBase->getBaseUsers() before persisting data it show me that my users are here, and don't throw any error.
But it seems data is not persisted after **$entitymanager->flush()**

Comment: The owner of the relation is `BaseUser` so the question is not only if `$groupBase->getBaseUsers()` contains baseUsers, but also if those baseUsers have the reference to the `GroupBase`. Seeing your code it seems to have ( `$baseUser->addGroupBase($this);` ) but i'ld look at that first.

Comment: I do have the group referenced in BaseUser's groupBase's collection. 
Thanks to you I've added these group when performing the insertion.
But stil no persistance. This was helping, I'm looking this way thanks

Comment: So it's like if the cascade is not operating. What if you persist users manually in the same time ? `foreach ($group->getBaseUsers() as $baseUser) { $entityManager->persist($baseUser); }` ?

Comment: Could you please provide the $groupBase property of the owner side ? the `mappedBy="GroupBase"` with the uppercase is triggering me, did you made this manually ? It could be a side effect of a mapping error.

Comment: I got it wrong indeed on uppercase, but both side are similar, it's posted

Comment: This is a gist of the baseCode
https://gist.github.com/lobamo/209d67b71fad18dc61e20d7a411e2780

Comment: In the Gist there's no cascade persist from GroupBase to baseUsers

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the gist you provided - https://gist.github.com/lobamo/209d67b71fad18dc61e20d7a411e2780

I see that Entity/User.php has the following:

```
abstract class BaseUser
{
```

Was this done intentionally? I believe that an Entity should not be an abstracted class.

Per PHP's definition found at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

> Classes defined as abstract cannot be instantiated, and any class that contains at least one abstract method must also be abstract.

Comment: I did this either by cascade or manually persisting both, but neither persist my collections in my entities

Comment: Yes, the abstract class was done intentionnaly, I have two Users class that extends the BaseUser.

Comment: I actually instantiate the subclasses when performing database operations